# Reversing my encrypt method

Tags: javascript

I created minor encrypt method to convert a small string based on distance between characters, but can't for the life of me figure out how to reverse it without knowing the distance between each character from the initial conversion. See image for example how it works imgur.com/Ine4sBo.png

I've already made the encrypt method here (Javascript):

```
var all = ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890.#-?").split('');
    var position;
    //var oKey = "P";



    function encrypt() // Encrypt Fixed
    {

        var sEncode = ("HI-MOM").split('');
        var oKey = "P";

        for (var i = 0; i < sEncode.length; i++) {
            if (all.indexOf(oKey) < all.indexOf(sEncode[i])) {                    
                position = all.indexOf(sEncode[i]) - all.indexOf(oKey);
                output.value += "oKey: " + oKey + " distance to sEncode[" + i + "]: " + sEncode[i] + " Count: " + position + " Final Char: " + all[position-1] + "\n";
                oKey = sEncode[i];
            }
            else {                    
                position = all.length - all.indexOf(oKey) + all.indexOf(sEncode[i]);
                output.value += "oKey: " + oKey + " distance to sEncode[" + i + "]: " + sEncode[i] + " Count: " + position + " Final Char: " + all[position-1] + "\n";
                oKey = sEncode[i];
            }


        }
    }
```

However, it's the decrypt() method that's killing me.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: If you don't know how the encryption method works how is anyone suppose to help you reverse the algorithm?

Comment: The code isn't even an encryption function....

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, your `encrypt` function can be reduced to this:

```
var all = ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890.#-?").split('');
function encrypt(str)
{
    var sEncode = str.split('');
    var result = '';
    var oKey = "P";
    for(var i = 0; i < sEncode.length; i++)
    {
        result += all[(all.indexOf(sEncode[i]) - all.indexOf(oKey) + all.length - 1) % all.length];
        oKey = sEncode[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

(I got rid of the if clause by adding `all.length` either way, and removing it again with the remainder operator if necessary.)

From there, all you need to do is flip the operands (`- all.indexOf(oKey) - 1` becomes `+ all.indexOf(oKey) + 1` (and since we have no more subtractions, adding `all.length` is no longer necessary)) and reverse the order (so `oKey` gets assigned the *transformed* value instead of the original one):

```
var all = ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890.#-?").split('');
function decrypt(str)
{
    var sEncode = str.split('');
    var result = '';
    var oKey = "P";
    for(var i = 0; i < sEncode.length; i++)
    {
        oKey = all[(all.indexOf(sEncode[i]) + all.indexOf(oKey) + 1) % all.length];
        result += oKey;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I was flipping the operands a couple of days ago I guess it didnt work out for me when I did i. I sat for 45 minute today trying to figure this damn thing out i.imgur.com/YbJAMXb.jpg on paper and i still came up short somewhere.